# Named Entity Recognition failing to show lists

Tags: python, tags, token, named-entity-recognition

The idea is that I'm using Named Entity Recognition (NER) on a tokenised text which is also tagged.

```
def make_tag_lists(sents):
    tokens=[]
    pos=[]
    ner=[]
    for sent in sents:
        for t in sent:
            tokens.append(t.text)
            pos.append(t.pos_)
            ner.append(t.ent_type_)
    return tokens,pos,ner

tokens,pos,ner = make_tag_lists(sample)

def extract_entities(tokenlist,taglist,tagtype):
    entities={}
    inentity=False
    for i,(token,tag) in enumerate(zip(tokenlist,taglist)):
        if tag==tagtype:
            if inentity:
                entity+=" "+token
            else:
                entity=token
                inentity=True
        elif inentity:
            entities[entity]=entities.get(entity,0)+1
            inentity=False
    return entities

people=extract_entities(tokens,ner,"PERSON")
top_people=sorted(people.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)[:20]
print(top_people)
```

What I should be receiving is the top 20 most commonly referred to people in a list, though my output is currently an empty list. There are no syntax errors and not sure where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Your indentation of your second function is broken.

Comment: tokens,pos,ner = make_tag_lists(x) ... what is x?

Comment: x is sentences ready to be tagged

Comment: Edit your post showing what x is... provide a Minimal Working example so we can test it

Comment: Edited with a small sample, there are definitely some "PERSON" tags in there

Comment: @petezurich yes sorry just an error I've made posting here

Comment: Please edit sample... it doesn't make any sense like this... should it be strings? Trying to execute the script results in SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187046/discussion-between-loss-of-human-identity-and-bemzoo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you trying to skip the first block of your code and check the remaining execution flow.

```
# tokens,pos,ner = make_tag_lists(sample)
tokens = ['Hi','FOO','BAR',"it's",'ME']
ner =['MISC','PERSON','PERSON','MISC','PERSON']
def extract_entities(tokenlist,taglist,tagtype):
    entities={}
    inentity=False
    for i,(token,tag) in enumerate(zip(tokenlist,taglist)):
        if tag==tagtype:
            if inentity:
                entity+=" "+token
            else:
                entity=token
                inentity=True
        elif inentity:
            entities[entity]=entities.get(entity,0)+1
            inentity=False
    return entities

people=extract_entities(tokens,ner,"PERSON")
top_people=sorted(people.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)[:20]
print(top_people)
```

The outcome of this example is `[('FOO BAR', 1)]`.
Furthermore, please notice that you are missing the last PERSON entity because it is not added to the `entities` dictionary.